# Solve $f'=f$ using fourier transform.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I'm trying to solve $f'=f$ using fourier transform. I know that $$\hat f'(\alpha )=2i\pi \alpha  \hat f(\alpha )$$
therefore
$$f'=f\iff 2i\pi \alpha \hat f(\alpha )=\hat f(\alpha )\iff \hat f(\alpha )=0\iff f(x)=0,$$

what wrong ? Because the solution should be $f(x)=e^{x}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fourier transform is not defined for the exponential (the integral does not converge). So what you are proving is that $f'=f$ only has the zero solution within the domain of the Fourier transform (say, $L^1(\mathbb R)$).

Note that you say "the solution should be $e^x$". But $f=0\ $ **is** a solution of $f'=f$, and it is the only one in the domain of the Fourier transform.

Comment: And the set of all solutions are $f(x) = C e^x$ for different constants $C$. The solution $f=0$ corresponds to $C=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$2i\pi \alpha f(\alpha) = f(\alpha)$ implies $f=0$ *or* $ f$ has support in $\{\alpha = 0\}$. Only for the first case a solution in $L^2$ exists, in the second case it's in the distributional sense.